# issue accessing mainwindow children of the tabitem (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

i m having my application mainWindow, and in this there are two tabs - tab1 and tab2.
After clicking on a particular button say buttonx if tab1 is selected. for the following

```
 Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
 Telerik.Windows.Controls.Label TickerName = mainWindow.ChildrenOfType<Telerik.Windows.Controls.Label>().First(e => e.Name.Equals("Ticker_Name"));
```

i get a exception that - **matching sequence not found.**

As my label is in tab2.
 for every element -as children of tab2 gets this exception.
its vice -versa the same if tab 2 is in current focus and buttonx is clicked, tab1 elements accessing raises exception.
Other elements which m accessing are not in both the tab does not get any exception.

Comment: As per your namespace Telerik.Windows.Controls it seems like you are using Telerik control. Is that true? than you might also have used RadTabControl for tabcontrol in wpf. in that case please refer this link : http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtabcontrol-how-to-keep-content.html

Comment: no sir, its simple tab not the radtabcontrol..!!